# "Choose your tech stack" tag box bug

Tags: bug, developer-story

The "Personal tech stack" tag box on the first stage of the "Choose your tech stack" section of the developer story isn't scrollable. You can click into the white space and use the arrow keys to navigate but this seems very clunky. I assume it is a bug?

[image]

Chrome 49.0.2623.87
Mac OS X 10.11.4

Comment: This is also a problem in the current Jobs UI and incredibly annoying/confusing. I think I spent more time mucking about with getting the tags right than anything else on my CV...

Comment: Majority of developers don't have enough techs to fill more than 2 lines.

Comment: @Sinatr The box is automatically filled for you.

Comment: @Sinatr So what? That doesn't mean it shouldn't work for those who do.

Comment: +1 for free-hand red circles, and bonus points for the free-hand red text.

Comment: -1 for not using a compass for those free-hand red circles, and stencils for the red text. ;)

Comment: Can we please bump this since it has been over a YEAR and this is still really annoying.