# Filling in developer story multiple issues

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

So, i'm trying to fill in my developer story and i'm encountering some bugs/usability aspects

I'm filling in the Technologies field, and I can't scroll in it. I can't even select the text and drag upwards to get stuff into view.

[image: Technologies]

Also, when I add a technology and click it, the watch/unwatch tag window pops up and stays there, blocking my view.

https://i.imgur.com/o3ky47h.gifv shows the issue.

Comment: I reported the Technology field bug over two years ago. Still not fixed. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320228/choose-your-tech-stack-tag-box-bug

Comment: Luckely it's an easy fix, right click inspect element, set height from 80px to 380px and it's workable again. But annoying none the less.

Comment: @Tschallacka that sounds a bit advanced, you should list HTML as one of your technologies ;)

Comment: Heh, i was just playing around for the first time with it :-) just listed everything i could think of out of the top of my head. Needs a do-over, the descriptions too. Will do maybe in another year and a half.

Comment: @Turnip It's probably the most annoying thing about Stackoverflow. It's owned by developers, so you guess the changes would be made fast and be constant, but it takes 6months to fix/add a small feature. To the Stackoverflow team this really isn't a bug. It's a feature request :/ and they have a huge backlog of requested features. You see sites like Quora/Medium and that they are constantly changing. They're amazing in that sense...

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for the delay. We haven't had a team working on the developer story feature for a while. We've added a scrollbar to the technologies section. This fix will be going out shortly with our next production build.

Thanks very much for your report.